# How to retrieve value from Array Class type object in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, class, object

I have method to call getSystem() by passing parameter ipadd, I have two class as mentioned below

```
SystemReport Class

public class SystemReport
{
    protected System[] system;

    public ComputerSystemResponse ()
    {
    }

    public void setSystems( System[] system )
    {
        this.system = system;
    }

    public System[] getSystem()
    {
        return system;
    }

}
```

System Class where site details reside which i'm interested in,

```
public class System 
{

protected String site;

 public System()
  {
  }

  public System(String site)
  {
  this.site=site;
  }

  public void setSite(String site) 
  {
        this.site = site;
  }

    public String getSite() 
    {
        return site;
    }

}
```

Method in different class & trying to retrieve value of site through looping

```
SystemReport rep = classInstance.getNames(ipadd);
System[] test = rep.getSystem();
```

Return type of getNames

```
protected SystemReport getNames (ipadd)
{
  SystemReport rep = new SystemReport();

  return rep;
}
```

Answering Questions:
1. classInstance.getNames(ipadd) has return type of SystemReport
2. rep size is > 0

now i would like to get site from rep, I tried checking the length by doing **test.length is 0**. What am i missing ?

Comment: What's the problem? WHat code are you executing, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: what is returned from this: `classInstance.getNames(ipadd);`

Comment: need to look at `getNames`.. How does it return's `SystemReport`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `getNames` function returns a new, blank instance of a SystemReport. You call `new SystemReport()` but the default constructor doesn't add anything to the list, so length would be 0.

You need to call `setSystems` on your created report and pass in wherever you get your `System[] system` array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
SystemReport rep = new SystemReport();
rep.setSystems((classInstance.getNames(ipadd)).getSystem());
```